# Setting value in Select2 using javascript object as data source

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I have a select2 initialized by following:

```
$('#bookingResource').select2({
    placeholder: "Select Resource",
    minimumInputLength: 0,
    multiple: true,
    allowClear: true,
    data: function() {
        return {results: sections };
    }
});
```

Sections is an object with the `id` and `text` keys used by select2.

I need to preselect a value using only the ID from another object.

```
$('#bookingResource').select2("val", object.resourceID);
```

I think I need to use the `initSelection` function, but I'm unsure how to formulate it so that I can return the text corresponding to the ID in the section object...

When I try and use the following initSelection example shown in the Select2 and call `.select2("val"...` I get no output at all.

```
initSelection : function (element, callback) {
        var data = [];
        $(element.val().split(",")).each(function () {
            data.push({id: this, text: this});
        });
        callback(data);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [docs](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation) of `initSelection` is rather unclear on this one. The key is to notice that `initSelection`

> [is supposed to process a value](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/2086#issuecomment-33515696).

and

> [The function will only be called when there is initial input to be processed](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation).

After some [testing](http://jsfiddle.net/ivan_sim/2ftk5c8z/), I notice that `initSelection` is called either when:

1. `.select2('val', $preselect_non_empty_value)` is called, or
2. The corresponding HTML element has specified a non-empty `value` attribute.

Depending on how you retrieve your `sections` data, my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivan_sim/2ftk5c8z/) may or may not answer your question. The first `select2` calls `.select2('val', 4)` to set 4 to be the pre-selected ID of the object. The second `select2` simply uses `element.val()` to pull the value from the HTML attribute.

Also, most examples on `initSelection` I have seen so far seems to expect the HTML element to contain some initial values. Otherwise, they do some AJAX thing. For example,

```
var id=$(element).val();
if (id!=="") {
    $.ajax($some_url, {
        //...
    }).done(function(data) { 
        callback(data); // data must be a single object
    });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Ivan, Thanks for your answer and the fiddle! It's almost there but as you will notice in your fiddle value 2 is actually returning item 3 because it is scoping to the ID of the object (which starts at 0) rather than the id within the object... Does this make sense?

Comment: Hi @Tim, good catch! I had mistaken the `ID` with the index of the array. I have updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivan_sim/2ftk5c8z/) to compare the values with the IDs within each objects, along with multiple pre-selected values. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi @isim, Thanks for fixing that! It works really well! Unfortunately my object is multidimensional, so some elements have children so this function does not work for those children. However I realise this is outside the scope of this question and your solution addresses my original question perfectly.